# SAML based Single Sign On Authentication to Netflix

Tags: python, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, netflix, onelogin

I'm trying to build a dashboard for myself that provides SAML based authentication to some Applications that I'm using.

From what I have built as a testbed:

I'm using One login as an Identity Provider to Apps that I want to use.

Case in point here: For Netflix, I'm being re-routed to Netflix page and my user ID and password is prefilled in there, just like how a password manager works. (It uses OneLogin's extension)

Does Netflix allow SAML based Single Sign-On authentication? I couldn't gather any definitive details from google searches so reached out here hoping someone might have built something on that front.

If yes, can someone point me to some article that I can follow along or even the caveats that I need to ensure for SAML-based SSO to Netflix?

Answer (score 0):

Other sites like Bitium https://www.bitium.com/netflix-saml-provider also does not use SAML for authenticating.

I feel it highly unlikely that Netflix and services like it would use SAML authentication with "home made" IDPs. Problem is that if Netflix choose to use your server as IDP, they then have to trust that you will authenticate users correctly and then tell them who the user is. And how would they be able to trust that your IDP actually tells them the correct user name. If you have control over the IDP you could just say that you are me and Netflix would accept it.

Comparing to other solutions like SAML against Google Apps or SalesForce. In this case Google and SalesForce trusts that your organisation IDP to authenticate users, but only among your organisations users. The IDP of "Toms boats" would not be able to authenticate users in the Apple organisation. In Netflix there are no organisations and there would in that case have to be a IDP per user. It would not be technically impossible, but its not really the way SAML was meant to be used ad would result in alot of work at Netflix for a use case that few would need.

Sorry but I think you are stuck with autofilling forms.